# ajax post method and php

Tags: php, ajax, post, authentication

Ho all, here I explain my problem (as far as i red i didnt find any working solution).
here I link my files:

progetto.html

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="funzioni.js"></script>
    <title>Pagina iniziale</title>
</head>
<body align='center'>
    <p>Gymnasium</p>
    <p>icona</p>
    <form id="ajaxForm" name="ajaxForm">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td><label>Utente</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="user" id="user" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Password</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Accedi" onclick='submitForm()' />
    </form>
    <div id="risultato"></div>
</body>
```

javascript file

```
function createXMLHttpRequestObject(){
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { return new XMLHttpRequest(); }
if (window.ActiveXObject) { return new ActiveXObject(Microsoft.XMLHTTP); }
return null;
```

}

```
function submitForm(){
var ajax = createXMLHttpRequestObject();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200){
                        var response = ajax.responseText;
                        document.getElementById("risultato").innerHTML = response;
                    }
                }
ajax.open("post", "ajaxLogin.php", true);
var data = "utente=" + document.getElementById('user').value + "&password=" + document.getElementById('password').value; 
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajax.send(data);
```

}

ajaxLogin.php

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST["user"]) || !isset($_POST["password"])){
    die("Bad login");
}
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pwd = $_POST['password'];
if ( (($user == "angel") && ($pwd == "devil")) || (($user == "john") && ($pwd == "smith")) ){
    $response = "Benvenuto  " . $user;
    echo $response;
}
```

?>

Problem is I always receive Bad Login message even if I use the right user and password.
It's a POST problem with I'm really having hard time figuring out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is your data:

```
var data = "utente=" + document.getElementById('user').value + "&password=" + document.getElementById('password').value;
```

And this is what you are checking:

```
if (!isset($_POST["user"]) || !isset($_POST["password"])){
```

You should change `utente` to `user` or the other way around. In your form you are using `user` as well so I would recommend using that everywhere.

So:

```
var data = "user=" + document.getElementById('user').value + "&password=" + document.getElementById('password').value;
```

Comment: @user3184908 You're welcome, please don't forget to mark the anwer as accepted if it solved your problem.